# Where can I find the command that start my container in azure app service for containers

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-container-registry, azure-appservice

My apologies if this is basic question but I'm new to the azure world.

My question is: Where can I find the "docker run" command that azure is executing to launch my container.

The reason is that I'm having a hard time running the container over https and I wonder if it has anything to do with the port mapping/environment variables that azure sets in the "docker run" command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can find the information about the start command `docker run` in the container logs like below:

[image]

But you have no control over the `docker run` command. What you can do to start the container is to set the startup command, this command will overwrite the `CMD` command in the Dockerfile. And if you need to find the information about the port mapping and environment variables, you can search them in the configuration:

[image]